# Swipe gesture added to UILabel, but its not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uilabel, uigesturerecognizer

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipedGesture:)];
swipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
 swipe.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
  [self.myLabel.superview addGestureRecognizer:swipe];

- (void)swipedGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"I swiped ;)");
}
```

So, this is what happens: I have a label called `myLabel`. and when I swipe right it should print the `NSLog` `I swiped`, but nothing happens. What's the reason? What have I done wrong here? Could someone help me edit my code to make this work ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dont you need to add this swipe gesture to the `UILabel`? you are adding it to the superview of that label.

change - `[self.myLabel.superview addGestureRecognizer:swipe];`

to - `[self.myLabel addGestureRecognizer:swipe];`

UPDATE: Also as justin points, please set `userInteractionEnabled` to `YES` for the label like so - `[self.myLabel setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];`

Comment: Could you please tell me what `adding it to the superview of that label` means ? Am i adding it to the `View` it self and not the label ?

Comment: yes I believe you are adding the gesture to the `view` which has the `uilabel`. So yes you seem to add the gesture to the view & not the label...

Comment: @harshitgupta, thanks! Please consider upvoting if my answer has helped you :)

Answer (score 10):

The gesture recognizer won't work unless you set `userInteractionEnabled` to `YES` on the label.